# How to delete and update using php

Tags: php, pdo

Hello guys I have been trying to delete a file using php and I want it to delete the main post, reply's and like then update to the author -10 in his/her point.

Here is my code, using PDO:

```
<?php session_start(); 
    if(isset($_POST['id'])){

        include($root . 'dbconn.php');

        $form = $_POST;
        $id = $form['id'];   
        try {

            $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
            $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM code WHERE cid= {$id}");
            $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM comment WHERE id = {$id}");
            $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM likes_map WHERE lid = {$id}");
            $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET point -1 WHERE username = {$u}");
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':cid', $id); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':lid ', $id);
            $stmt->bindParam(':u ', $_SESSION['username']);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "deleted"
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $db_conn = null;


    }else{
        echo "You are not allow to delete this";
    }
?>
```

Comment: and your question/problem is?

Comment: @RST is not working it will show deleted but nothing will happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are preparing more than one query on the same statement handle and therefore loosing the link to that prepared statement when you prepare the next query.

You are also only executing the queries once and not once per statement!

Also your prepared sql statement do not have the parameters set with the correct syntax

It would also be a good idea to run this code inside a transaction, so if any update of the database fails you are not left with just bits of this process comepleted. This assumes the database is an INNODB database and not an MYISAM one, as transactions dont work on MYISAM

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    if(!isset($_POST['id'])){
        echo "You are not allow to delete this";
        exit;
    }

    include($root . 'dbconn.php');

    $form = $_POST;
    $id = $form['id'];   
    try {

        $db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
        $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // start a transaction
        $db_conn->beginTransaction();

        $d_code = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM code WHERE cid= :id");
        $d_code->bindParam(':id', $id); 

        $d_comment = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM comment WHERE id = :id");
        $d_comment->bindParam(':id', $id); 

        $d_like = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM likes_map WHERE lid = :id");
        $d_like->bindParam(':id ', $id);

        $u_user = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET point -1 WHERE username = :u");
        $u_user->bindParam(':u ', $_SESSION['username']);


        $d_code->execute();
        $d_comment->execute();
        $d_like->execute();
        $u_user->execute();

        $db_conn->commit();

        echo "deleted";

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $db_conn->rollBack();
        echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $db_conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: Glad to be of assistance